# ExtJS - EditorGridPanel: error when cell is selected

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid

I'm getting an error when selecting cells in my **EditorGridPanel**. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
var bannerGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: bannerStore,             
    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            sortable: true,
            menuDisabled: true
        },
        columns:
            { 
                header: '<img src="img/oo-icon.png" />&nbsp;<img src="img/network-icon.png" />', 
                width: 52, 
                dataIndex: 'inventory', 
                align: 'center',
                renderer: inventoryIcon,
            }, { 
                header: "Name", 
                dataIndex: 'bannerName',
                editor: new Ext.form.TextField({ allowBlank: false }),
                width: 300
            }, { 
                header: "Advertiser", 
                dataIndex: 'advertiser',
                editor: advertisersDropdownGrid,
            }, { 
                header: "Art Type", 
                dataIndex: 'artType',
                editor: artTypeDropdownGrid,
            }, {
        ......
```

Each of the 'editors' are dropdowns that are defined prior to the grid. The weird thing is that the editor that contains the **TextField** does not throw the same error.

The error I'm getting when selecting a cell is this:

```
c.getItemCt() is undefined
[Break On This Error] c.getItemCt().removeClass('x-hide-' + c.hideMode);
```

Again, **this only happens on the ComboBox editors!**

From further inspection the error is coming from this part of ext itself:

```
onFieldShow: function(c){
c.getItemCt().removeClass('x-hide-' + c.hideMode);
    if (c.isComposite) {
        c.doLayout();
    }
},
```

Which seems to be part of the **FormLayout** section.

Any ideas? I've tried defining the Combo's inline and that did not fix it.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's how I define my Combo's using classes.

I define my ComboBoxJSON class: (I've blanked out namespaces just for privacy sake)

```
***.***.***.ComboBoxJSON = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {

    url: '',
    root: '',
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    width: 200,
    id: '',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int'}, 
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ],


    initComponent: function () {

        var comboStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
               id: 'JsonStore',
               idProperty: 'id',
               autoLoad: true,
               idProperty: 'id',
               root: this.root,
               fields: this.fields,
               proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
                   api: {
                       read: this.url,
                   }
               })
           });  

        var config = {
            store: comboStore,
            displayField: this.displayField,
            valueField: this.valueField,
            mode: 'local',
            minChars: 1,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            typeAhead: true,
            lazyRender: true,
            value: this.value,
            width: this.width,
            id: this.id
        }

        Ext.apply(this, config);

        ***.***.***.ComboBoxJSON.superclass.initComponent(this);

    }
});

Ext.reg("ibwComboJson", ***.***.***.ComboBoxJSON);
```

I then define my combos before init on the grid, like so: (I've blocked out the URL, but it does return valid JSON)

```
var advertisersDropdownGrid = new ***.***.***.ComboBoxJSON({
    url: '***',
    root: 'advertiserList',
    id: 'advertisersDropdownGrid'           
});
```

Comment: A working showcase would help (http://wwww.sencha.com/learn/Ext_Forum_Help#Posting_a_working_showcase)

Comment: can you show us `advertisersDropdownGrid`?

Comment: I just noticed your columns property in the column model is wrong, your column objects should be in an array which is assigned to the `columns` property, is that just a copy and paste mistake?

Comment: @Jaitsu: yeah, just a copy paste mistake
Let me try and get a working example up for you guys.

Comment: can you show us your combobox code?

Comment: Edited my original answer for you, Jaitsu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this awhile back, but the solution is pretty absurdly simple.

```
***.***.***.ComboBoxJSON.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
```

Forgot the `.call` portion. :)